# How to use Vuejs inside a custom control?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm building a custom control and would like to use Vuejs however I'm having trouble with Vuejs not being able to recognize the base element. I keep getting an error saying the element doesn't exist.

I'm guessing this is because the settings are loaded via ajax. I've tried loading the script with the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` hook but I can't get it working.

Any idea how to sort this out?

Thank you.

Comment: It is very hard to answer questions of the type "Something is not working" without seeing your code, and a better explanation of what is working and what not. Code or better description of how you are using VUE and integrating with the customizer will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following the example found in [Customize React Street Address Control](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-react-street-address-control), but using Vue instead of React.

Comment: sorry, link only answers are not answers at all around here unless they are internal or lead to canonical content (and even than they will be snobed at) . Sooner or later this link will rot and the answer will be useless

Comment: Fair enough. But it's hard to provide more than a link without there being more code in the question to work with.

Comment: I assume the question is more about what assets needs to be enqueued and how to access the control itself. Specifically sounds like the OP do not know how to "reconnect" to the widget after an update had happened. Will leave a comment for him as well.

Comment: Apologies for not providing enough information. My issue was that Vue wasn't able to find the elements where to attach the instance, this because I suppose fields are loaded via ajax.

Anyways I've managed to get Vue to load into the customizer... I had to run the instance by binding it to the customizer's "ready" event, although for some reason the instance was being called twice so in the end I switched to jquery because I was in a rush.

Also thanks for the react example that looks much better than what I was trying to do.